# Delete everything except a few extensions

Tags: command-line, rm

Can I modify the `rm` command with regular expression or something to delete.
every file in current directory except files with extensions `*.bmp`, `*.wav` and `*.png`? It should be case insensitive because there are files like `*.BMP` or `*.bMP`.

Comment: `mv` all `*.bmp, *.wav, *.png` to newdir. Then `rm -rf dir`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@ChrisDown has given [a `bash` solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27745) that takes into account the difference of files and directories, and also if there is no file to remove.

Given that `rm` would fail however in these situations, the command could be simplified as (still with `bash`):

```
shopt -s extglob nocaseglob
rm -- !(*.bmp|*.wav|*.png)
```

Remember to reset the two shell options to their default values. In my case `extglob` is already set on interactive shells, so I only need

```
shopt -u nocaseglob
```

Or run those two commands in a subshell:

```
(shopt -s extglob nocaseglob
rm -- !(*.bmp|*.wav|*.png))
```

If you would like to see in advance what files will be removed, simply substitute the `rm` with `echo`.

If you would like hidden files to be removed as well, add the `dotglob` option.

Comment: @enzolib This is already out of the scope of the question, but I used commas instead of `|` and everything from the directory was deleted (nothing important, so I downloaded it again), but I can imagine the danger of this command. Is there some less severe command with possibility of backup?

Comment: @enzolib I see you edited the question and your last sentence is very useful.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `bash`, you can use a combination of `extglob` and `nocaseglob`.

```
shopt -s extglob nocaseglob
for file in !(@(*.bmp|*.wav|*.png)); do
    [[ -f "${file}" ]] && files+=( "${file}" )
done
(( ${#files[@]} )) && rm "${files[@]}"
```

Otherwise you can us something like the following:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! \( -iname '*.bmp' -o -iname '*.wav' -o \
    -iname '*.png' \) -delete
```

Comment: -exec rm {} can be replaced with -delete

Comment: Thank you for this complex command. Actually I was looking for something more simple, to be able to use it quickly, when I have a need. So enzolib's solution is more convenient for my common needs.

Comment: @xralf Bear in mind that that will not only remove regular files, however...

Comment: @ChrisDown That's quite strange, because I usually have to use `rm -r` to remove directories.

Comment: @xralf It's not only directories that are not regular files.

Answer (score 4):

With  `zsh`, to remove the *regular* files other than the `.bmp`, `.png`, `.wav` (case insensitively) ones:

```
setopt extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
rm -- ^*.(#i)(png|bmp|wav)(D.)
```

(remove the `D` above if you want to preserve hidden files regardless of their extension).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you take a little time and do this in multiple steps so you do not do anything accidently silly.

1. create a command to identify the files you want to delete, e.g.

   ```
       ls | grep -v *.bmp | grep -v *.wav  # current directory
   ```

   or

   ```
       find . -type f | grep -v *.bmp      # current and sub directories
   ```

   if the list of returned files is what you want to remove, then
2. recall the last command and add the `xargs rm` command to it, e.g.

   ```
       ls | grep -v *.bmp | grep -v *.wav | xargs rm
   ```

Comment: I don't understand why you consider using `grep -v` instead of `find`'s inbuild `! -iname` any safer. Not to mention that this doesn't work in a case-insensitive fashion as requested in the question, and will break on newlines.

Comment: Not to mention that `grep -v *.bmp` doesn't make any sense, you probably meant `grep -v '\.bmp$'`.